# WPF How to get current edited content in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Given a data-grid bound to a CollectionViewSource who's source is an ObservableCollection, when first displayed the OC is instantiated to show a single row with nothing in it.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="observationNameColumn"  Width="auto" Header="Observation Name" Binding="{Binding ObservationName}"/>
```

I want to enter text in any of the given fields to kick off a EF back end query based on user input.  To do this I added a button like this to the same data-grid.  A simple button with a click handler...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="XBTNSearch"  Click="XBTNSearch_Click" Padding="5,0,5,0">Enter Search Criteria and Search</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When the row is clicked with the edited value this is the type of code used.

```
    private void XBTNSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
        Debugger.Break();
        FindStuff();
    }
```

When the break point is hit is shows an empty model of the observable collection type even though I did type something into one of the fields...  I want that value so I can use EF to 'FindStuff'

How do I get the value in the row cell based on the Button's datacontext which should be that very row I edited the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was this in the Button click event Hanlder as the first statement...

```
    XDG.CommitEdit();
```

Where XDG is the Xaml Data Grid....